# Serialize genereted classes from ADO.NET entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, serialization, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have the following table:

```
create table Movie
(
    id integer primary key identity(1,1),
    title varchar(40),
    synopsis varchar(200),
    movieLength integer,
    imageSmall varbinary(max),
    imageLarge varbinary(max),
    inputDate date,
);
```

Using ADO.NET entity model, I generated C# classes.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CinemaService
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
            this.Show = new HashSet<Show>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string synopsis { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> movieLength { get; set; }
        public byte[] imageSmall { get; set; }
        public byte[] imageLarge { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> inputDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Show> Show { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the following contract:

```
namespace CinemaService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICinemaService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Movie[] list_movies();
    }
}
```

And service:

```
namespace CinemaService
{
    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class CinemaService : ICinemaService
    {
        private CinemaEntities _entities;

        public CinemaService()
        {
            _entities = new CinemaEntities();
        }

        public Movie[] list_movies()
        {
            return _entities.Movie.ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

The service is hosted on IIS.

When the table is empty, I am able to invoke and get results (empty result), but when there is even one row, I get an exception.

I enabled tracing in web.config, and I think the problem is that the generated classes are not serializable.

Using trace viewer, I found the following:

Exception type:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Message:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:list_moviesResult. The InnerException message was
>   'Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Movie_46EC56490AEEEA50CA29379C6E09B01C345ECBB1273756AE368BA72AA30754B5'
>   with data contract name
>   'Movie_46EC56490AEEEA50CA29379C6E09B01C345ECBB1273756AE368BA72AA30754B5:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Disable proxy generation in your entity model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

I deleted the generated classes, and downloaded a new code generation item template: EF 6.x EntityObject Generator. (I used DBContext generator).

Now it works fine.

Comment: That would not be the recommended approach. Although technically this could possibly work, exposing persistence objects on a communication layer often leads to other issues (performance, security). Follow @Luis recommendation instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can achieve what you want using several methods like as described in one the comments (disable proxy generation).

If your architecture allows it I would recommend using [DTOs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) (Data Transfer Object) together with a mapping tool like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).